# Elasticsearch include field in result set of aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

How can field of type string be included in the result set of an aggregation?
For example given the following mapping:

```
{
 "sport": {
  "mappings": {
     "runners": {
        "properties": {
           "name": {
              "type": "string"
           },
           "city": {
              "type": "string"
           },
           "region": {
              "type": "string"
           },
           "sport": {
              "type": "string"
                }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Sample data:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/sport/_bulk" -d'
  {"index":{"_index":"sport","_type":"runner"}}
  {"name":"Gary", "city":"New York","region":"A","sport":"Soccer"}
  {"index":{"_index":"sport","_type":"runner"}}
  {"name":"Bob", "city":"New York","region":"A","sport":"Tennis"}
  {"index":{"_index":"sport","_type":"runner"}}
  {"name":"Mike", "city":"Atlanta","region":"B","sport":"Soccer"}
 '
```

How can the field `name` be included in result set of the aggregation:

```
{
"size": 0, 
"aggregations": {
  "agg": {
     "terms": {
        "field": "city"}
       }
     }
   }
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data and what you expect to see in the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do what you want, if I'm understanding you correctly:

```
POST /sport/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggregations": {
      "city_terms": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "city"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "name_terms": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "name"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

With the data you provided, it returns:

```
{
   "took": 43,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "city_terms": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "new",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "name_terms": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "bob",
                        "doc_count": 1
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "gary",
                        "doc_count": 1
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "york",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "name_terms": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "bob",
                        "doc_count": 1
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "gary",
                        "doc_count": 1
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "atlanta",
               "doc_count": 1,
               "name_terms": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "mike",
                        "doc_count": 1
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

(You may want to add `"index":"not_analyzed"` to one or both fields in your mapping, if these results are not what you were expecting.)

Here's the code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/07735aadc082c1c60409931c279f3fd85a340dbb